# invalid identifier in update statement in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two tables below:

```
hotel (**hotelNo**, hotelName, city)
room  (**roomNo**, type, price, hotelNo)
```

In table `hotel`, `hotelNo` is the primary key. In `room` table, `roomNo` is the primary key and `hotelNo` is the foreign key.

Now I want to increase the prices of all rooms at the Hyde Park Hotel by 5%. This is my statement:

```
UPDATE room SET price = price * 1.05
WHERE room.hotelNo = hotel.hotelNo AND hotel.hotelName = 'Hyde Park';
```

The oracle give me an error says `hotel.hotelName` is invalid identifier.
That's why? and how could I accomplish my task?

Comment: add hotel to your from clause

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
UPDATE room SET price = price * 1.05
WHERE hotelNo in (SELECT hotelNo FROM hotel WHERE hotelName = 'Hyde Park');
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, you are not `SELECT`ing the table HOTEL anywhere.

1. You can use inner query as below: **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ff14f/4)**

   ```
   UPDATE ROOM SET PRICE = PRICE * 1.05
   WHERE
   HOTELNO = (  
           SELECT  HOTELNO 
           FROM HOTEL
           WHERE
           HOTELNAME = 'Hyde Park'
        )
   ```
2. Another method using join(Untested, [Reference](https://community.oracle.com/thread/401752))

   ```
   UPDATE
   (
      SELECT  R.PRICE
      FROM   ROOM R INNER JOIN HOTEL H
      ON   R.HOTELNO = H.HOTELNO
      AND H.HOTELNAME = 'Hyde Park'
   )
   SET R.PRICE = R.PRICE * 1.05;
   ```

Comment: @user3368506: Have updated fiddle. Please check and upvote if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
 UPDATE room ,hotel SET price = price * 1.05
 WHERE room.hotelNo = hotel.hotelNo AND hotel.hotelName = 'Hyde Park';
```