# SQL Update table with nested Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I´m having problems with this query. I´having the error:

Invalid identifier

I want to update colum CONTACT from table MAIN with MSISDN from the nested query, where the N_ACCOUNT from MAIN matches ACCOUNT from the nested query

```
UPDATE MAIN

SET CONTACT = BASE.MSISDN

WHERE N_ACCOUNT IN 

                (
                   SELECT BASE.MSISDN, BASE.ACCOUNT

                    FROM (

                         SELECT  TBL1 AS MSISDN, TBL2 AS ACCOUNT

                         FROM    TBL3,
                                 TBL2,
                                 TBL1

                         WHERE   TBL2.DW_SUPP_SERV_ID=TBL3.DW_PRICEBL_ID
                             AND TBL3.DW_ORIG_SERV_ID = TBL1.DW_ORIG_SERV_ID
                             AND TBL2.SUPP_SERV_CODE IN 
                                    ('DAY37','DAYAP','DAYQA','DBY4G')
                             AND TBL3.DW_SUPP_SERV_ST_ID='100000001'


                         )BASE

                WHERE BASE.ACCOUNT=MAIN.N_ACCOUNT


              );
```

Comment: This link might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25131382/invalid-identifier-in-update-statement-in-oracle-sql

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: It isn't ANSI standard script, please use inner joins for tables within subquery

Comment: SQL Server um this case